SingleValueExtendedProperty for MailFolder order coming up null
I have the following call to an MS-Graph account:
IMailFolderChildFoldersCollectionPage chlds = await _graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders[MailFolderId].ChildFolders.Request().Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Binary 0x3020')").GetAsync();

According to the accepted answer at Graph APi - Get user Mailboxes in the order as in Outlook, this should give me a value that I can use to sort the folders in the same order they appear in the Outlook page.
But I get nulls, across the board. Is this because that value only gets added when a mailfolder's order is changed by the user? Is there any way to get the standard order (rather than alphabetical, which is how the folders are returned) if the user hasn't changed folder orders?
